# How to change font on Skype 5.3 (skypeforlinux) on Fedora 25

Tags: fonts, qt, skype

The previous recipe was to use qt4-config, which is no longer working as you can't select a qt4 related theme.

Any solution available? It's very small font on 4k monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but the only thing I found was zooming.

It affects the sidebar but at least the chats become more readible.

You can try the `Zoom in` shortcut `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`=` (I found it in `View`, where you can click directly).

Use `Ctrl`+`0` (what they called `Actual size`) to reset and `Ctrl`+`-` to minize the size.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it will work on Fedora, but on my Ubuntu I could achieve it by simply editing skypeforlinux bin and adding --force-device-scale-factor attribute:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/skypeforlinux
```

Changed:

```
nohup "$SKYPE_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$SKYPE_LOGS/skype-startup.log" 2>&1 &
```

To:

```
nohup "$SKYPE_PATH" --force-device-scale-factor=1.3 --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$SKYPE_LOGS/skype-startup.log" 2>&1 &
```